# Como desinstalar um app automaticamente antes de instalar novamente?

Tags: android, android-studio, emulador

Estou usando o Android Studio para testar e depurar meu aplicativo com as `library`s, mas o aplicativo não é sobreposto corretamente, por isso preciso que, antes de instala-lo, ele seja removido.

Testei com o `:app:uninstallDebug` e o `:app:uninstallAll` como descrito [aqui no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28076751/), mas nada acontece depois de executar o `Run`, só vejo os status `Gradle Build Running` e não sai disso. O projeto é simples, em questão de sugundos ele é compilado e instalado sem a configuração `:app:uninstallAll`.

A seguir os logs.

*Event Log*

> 17:18:16 Executing tasks: [:app:uninstallAll]

*Message Gradle Build*

> Information:Gradle tasks [:app:uninstallAll] :app:uninstallDebug
>   05:59:13 E/ddms:
>   'C:\Users\Desktop\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe,start-server'
>   failed -- run manually if necessary :app:uninstallDebug FAILED
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:uninstallDebug'.
>   > com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: Could not create ADB Bridge. ADB location:
>   C:\Users\Desktop\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
>   Information:BUILD FAILED Information:Total time: 4.216 secs
>   Information:1 error Information:0 warnings Information:See complete
>   output in console

*Gradle Console*

> Executing tasks: [:app:uninstallAll]
>
> Configuration on demand is an incubating feature. Incremental java
>   compilation is an incubating feature. :app:uninstallDebug

*idea.log*

> 2016-08-26 17:18:16,722 [1226128]   INFO -
>   a.gradle.invoker.GradleInvoker - About to execute Gradle tasks:
>   [:app:uninstallAll]  2016-08-26 17:18:16,773 [1226179] INFO -
>   s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from
>   C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_45

Como eu posso fazer para desinstalar um aplicativo antes de instalá-lo com o Android Studio, sem passar por esses problemas descritos acima? Como resolver isso?

Comment: Até a presente data, o `Gradle Build Running` ainda está em execução. Apenas fechando o processo para para-lo. `Android Studio 2.1.3`

Comment: Não sei se entendi muito bem o problema. Mas imagino que se refira ao Instant Run do Android Studio pois também tive alguns problemas com isso quando foi lançado. Pra desabilitar o Instant Run você vai em File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run e desativa tudo lá.

Comment: Não é sobre o _Instant Run_, mesmo com ele desabilitado, o app não é desinstalado, apenas sobrescrito, pois as librarys presentes no aquivo `.apk` ainda continuam, e não são removidas, bem como o próprio app, esse é o proposito desta pergunta, desinstalar antes de executar uma novo instalação. @MatheusdeMello

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o plugin do android studio chamado "ADB Idea" nela há comandos como Desinstalar uma aplicação, matar um app, dar um clear data, etc..

Para maior praticidade ainda você pode ou colocar um atalho para cada comando. Ou ainda você pode fazer uma macro que desinstale e instale o aplicativo.